# Run suites of included files in codeception

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I have an application with different modules. For each module, there are separate tests written which are divided in different suites.

For example in tests/Custom/codeception.yml

```
namespace: Test\Custom

paths:
    tests: .
    data: _data
    support: _support
    log: _output

coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: false
    whitelist: { include: ['../../../../src/*'] }

suites:
    Business:
        path: Business
    ...
    View:
        path: View
    ....
```

So every module has its own codeception.yml.
To have one "master config" there is a codeception.yml in the first level of the test folder which is including all the subfolder module yml with

```
namespace: Test
actor: Tester

include:
    - tests/*
...
```

When running a build caused by a branch update in the repository we usually don't want to run other tests than business because they are slow and fragile.

For this i try to run `codecept run Business` and expect, that just the Business suites from the included files will be executed.
But this will not work, instead i get the error message

```
Suite 'Business' could not be found
```

But when i run one module explicit with Business suite

```
codecept run -c tests/Custom Business
```

it works.

My first assumption was, that the files get not proper included to the master yml so i tried the general call

```
codecept run
```

and it works! But this unfortunately runs all suites.

So, why the suites cant be seen by the master codeception.yml? How can i run all tests Business suites without pointing explicit to the module path?

Thanks